# How to calculate average in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, average

I have `Category` and `Product` models below:

```py
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5)
```

Questions:

1. How can I average all the prices in `Product` model?
2. How can I average all the prices in `Product` model category by category?

Answer (score 22):

You can use aggregate and Avg in a django query.

Supposing your model Product field name is **price**:

```
from django.db.models import Avg

Product.objects.aggregate(Avg('price'))
Product.objects.aggregate(Avg('price'))
```

Comment: This does the average overall, however I need the average of each member if you understand me?

Comment: Yes! For example Aragorn has 34 wins and 27 losses. Jack has 2 wins and 18 losses. I need the average win rate for EACH member.

Comment: I think it is easier to use .values to get the wins and losses and do the calculation manually, it is simple math.

Answer (score 6):

```py
for category in Category.objects.all():
    stat = Product.objects.filter(category_id=category.id).aggregate(Avg('price'))['price__avg']`
```

[Django Aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/)

Answer (score 3):

You simply using [`values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values), [`aggregate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-over-a-queryset) and function [`Avg()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-over-a-queryset) and [`F()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F).

Let's assume You have `Model` like this:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=16, unique=True)

class MatchResult(models.Model):
    member = models.ForeignKey('Member')
    wins = models.IntegerField()
    losses = models.IntegerField()
```

Now You can aggregate those using this syntax (look at `__` [double underscore notation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#joins-and-aggregates)):

```
MatchResult.objects.values(
    'username_id', 
    'username__nickname', 
    'wins',
    'losses'
).aggregate(
    user_id=F('username_id'),
    nickname=F('username__nickname'),
    avg_wins=Avg('wins'),
    avg_losses=Avg('losses')
)
```

Please refer to [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregation).

**Hint:** [Order of annotate and filter clauses is **IMPORTANT**.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-filter-clauses)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [aggregate()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#aggregate) and [annotate()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.annotate) with [Avg()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#avg) to average the prices in `Product` model and category by category as shown below. *You need to use `order_by('pk')` with `annotate()` otherwise values are printed in descending order:

```py
from django.db.models import Avg

# Average the prices in "Product" model
print(
    "<All products>",
    Product.objects.aggregate(Avg('price'))
) 

print()

# Average the prices in "Product" model category by category
for obj in Category.objects.all(): 
    print(
        obj.id, obj.name,
        Product.objects.filter(category=obj)
                       .aggregate(Avg('price'))
    )

print()

# Average the prices in "Product" model category by category
for obj in Category.objects.all(): 
    print(
        obj.id, obj.name, 
        obj.product_set.aggregate(Avg('price'))
    )

print()

# Average the prices in "Product" model category by category
qs = Category.objects.annotate(Avg('product__price')).order_by('pk')
for obj in qs:
    print(obj.id, obj.name, obj.product__price__avg)
```

Then, these below are outputted on console:

```
<All products> {'price__avg': Decimal('20.1578947368421053')}

1 Fruits {'price__avg': Decimal('13.5714285714285714')}
2 Vegetable {'price__avg': Decimal('23.0000000000000000')}
3 Meat {'price__avg': Decimal('24.2500000000000000')}
4 Fish {'price__avg': Decimal('25.3333333333333333')}

1 Fruits {'price__avg': Decimal('13.5714285714285714')}
2 Vegetable {'price__avg': Decimal('23.0000000000000000')}
3 Meat {'price__avg': Decimal('24.2500000000000000')}
4 Fish {'price__avg': Decimal('25.3333333333333333')}

1 Fruits 13.5714285714285714
2 Vegetable 23.0000000000000000
3 Meat 24.2500000000000000
4 Fish 25.3333333333333333
```

And, you can change the default key `price__avg` and `product__price__avg` to `priceAvg` for **price** column as shown below:

```py
from django.db.models import Avg

# Average the prices in "Product" model
print(
    "<All products>",
    Product.objects.aggregate(priceAvg=Avg('price'))
)                             # ↑ Here

print()

# Average the prices in "Product" model category by category
for obj in Category.objects.all(): 
    print(
        obj.id, obj.name,
        Product.objects.filter(category=obj)
                       .aggregate(priceAvg=Avg('price'))
    )                             # ↑ Here

print()

# Average the prices in "Product" model category by category
for obj in Category.objects.all(): 
    print(
        obj.id, obj.name, 
        obj.product_set.aggregate(priceAvg=Avg('price'))
    )                             # ↑ Here

print()

# Average the prices in "Product" model category by category
qs = Category.objects.annotate(priceAvg=Avg('product__price')).order_by('pk')
for obj in qs:                 # ↑ Here
    print(obj.id, obj.name, obj.priceAvg)
                                # ↑ Here
```

Then, the default key is changed as shown below:

```
<All products> {'priceAvg': Decimal('20.1578947368421053')}

1 Fruits {'priceAvg': Decimal('13.5714285714285714')}
2 Vegetable {'priceAvg': Decimal('23.0000000000000000')}
3 Meat {'priceAvg': Decimal('24.2500000000000000')}
4 Fish {'priceAvg': Decimal('25.3333333333333333')}

1 Fruits {'priceAvg': Decimal('13.5714285714285714')}
2 Vegetable {'priceAvg': Decimal('23.0000000000000000')}
3 Meat {'priceAvg': Decimal('24.2500000000000000')}
4 Fish {'priceAvg': Decimal('25.3333333333333333')}

1 Fruits 13.5714285714285714
2 Vegetable 23.0000000000000000
3 Meat 24.2500000000000000
4 Fish 25.3333333333333333
```